# PHP/MYSQL Retrieve Name based on another criterion

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, pdo

So I have a login system and I want to retrieve the first name of the person who is logged in. Here's my php:

```
function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {
        $query = "SELECT `First Name`, Username, Password
                FROM table
                WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd
                LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':un', $un);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            // User exist
            return true;
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else {
            // User doesn't exist
            return false;
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
```

this is part of a class who has 1 private variable $conn. The login works perfectly but i just want to get the person's first name. How do I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, NEVER grab the password from the database, that is just extremely bad practice.

Second, you only want to accept the user as correct if ONLY one row is returned.

lastly `bindColumn` is what you're looking for.

```
<?php
function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {
    $query = "SELECT `First Name`, Username
              FROM table
              WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd";
    // Don't limit the query to only one, if there is a chance that you can
    // return multiple rows, either your code is incorrect, bad data in the database, etc...

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':un', $un);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Only assume proper information if you ONLY return 1 row.
    // Something is wrong if you return more than one row...
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        // User exist
        $stmt->bindColumn('First Name', $firstName);
        $stmt->bindColumn('Username', $username);
        // You can now refer to the firstName and username variables.
        return true;
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        // User doesn't exist
        return false;
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

That should work for you.

Comment: ah okay, thank you. What should I do instead for authenticating a login?

Comment: Well, you will want to hash your password in some capacity. Preferably not MD5, that is considered obsolete, it runs too quickly. That is a different question altogether. Just make sure you never ASK for the password from the database, you can always tell the database what the password might be, but if you grab it, there is a chance a person can read it. Which is a really bad idea...

Comment: ah okay, after getting this done i will be working on implementing bcrypt. Also, i tried your code putting `$stmt->bindColumn('First Name', $firstName);` in the if statement, but then i tried `die($firstName);` after that but nothing gets printed. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you actually echoing out the $firstName variable? it won't just print itself.

Comment: hmm i didn't try that. But my end goal is to put it in a session so i did something like this: `$stmt->bindColumn('First Name', $firstName);
   $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $firstName;
   die($_SESSION["FirstName"]);`                            this works for username but not firstname.

Comment: Double check to make sure that the first name field is filled out in your database?

Comment: yep just checked, it's there.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it may have an issue with you having called your field name `First Name`, try renaming the field to `first_name`... Databases are a little strange when you have field names or anything of the like that have spaces.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17462/discussion-between-charlie-yabben-and-justin-wood)

Answer (score 0):

just change the query statement?

```
    $query = "SELECT `First Name`
            FROM table 
            WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd 
            LIMIT 1";
```

if that throws errors, you would have to show more of what the class is doing to manage the db transaction

Answer (score 0):

just change this line, to select only `First Name` in the query:

```
 $query = "SELECT `First Name`, Username, Password
            FROM table
            WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd
            LIMIT 1";` 
     to 

 $query = "SELECT `First Name`
            FROM table
            WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd
            LIMIT 1";`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the result as below

```
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($fname, $uname, $pwd);
        $stmt->fetch()
        echo $fname // here you get firsname

        // either you can return this $fname or store into session variable for further

        // User exist
        return true;
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else {
        // User doesn't exist
        return false;
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the section where you are returning true you could instead return the actual user data (and array with data will evaluate to true anyway).

Word of warning, you should use hashed passwords. Do not store the password y plain.