# PHP Retrieiving Column Data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have an earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695162/php-mysql-retrieve-name-based-on-another-criterion/12695505#12695505)
But NONE of those answers worked. So here's my entire class code:

```
<?php
session_start();
class Mysql {
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn =  new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***;charset=UTF-8','***','***') or 
                      die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }

    function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {
        $query = "SELECT Username
                FROM Conference
                WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(':un', $un);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            // User exist
            $stmt->bindColumn('First Name', $firstName); 
            $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $firstName; 
            die($_SESSION["FirstName"]);
            return true;
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else {
            // User doesn't exist
            //die("failure");
            return false;
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I've tried fetch, i've tried bind_result, etc and none of them print the correct value on the die statement. Now this **worked** when i stored username in session and tried to print that. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the error? What does not work? And what does the `die($_SESSION["FirstName"]);` ?

Comment: @JvdBerg it literally prints nothing. But if i stored username then it prints the correct username. I've even tried the bindcolumn with back ticks and it still didn't retrieve the correct first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You aren't calling the code in the snippet. What's the call procedure?
2. You aren't retrieving `Conference.First Name` only `Conference.Username` so you should be getting a warning unless you're not displaying errors. You probably want

`"SELECT * FROM Conference...."`

or

`"SELECT FirstName From Conference WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd";`

1. It's possibly `Conference.FirstName`.
2. `die();` is not very useful for debugging. Try `var_dump($_SESSION["FirstName"]); die();`

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your code, and made a working version on my own server. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
class Mysql
{
  private $conn;
  public  $error;
  public  $username;

  function __construct()
  {
    try {
      $this->conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', 'root', '****' );
      $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

    }
    catch ( Exception $e ) {
       $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  function verify_Username_and_Pass( $un, $pwd )
  {
    $query = "SELECT Username
              FROM Conference
              WHERE Username = :un AND Password = :pwd";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    if( !$stmt ) {
      $this->error = $this->conn->errorInfo();
      return false;        
    }

    $stmt->bindParam( ':un', $un );
    $stmt->bindParam( ':pwd', $pwd );
    $stmt->execute();
    if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
      // User exist
      $this->username = $stmt->fetchColumn();
      return true;
    } 
    else {
      // User doesn't exist
      return false;
    }
  }

}

session_start();

$db = new Mysql();
if( !$db->error ) {
  if( $db->verify_Username_and_Pass ( 'user', 'test' )) {
    $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $db->username;
  }
  else
    echo 'Unknown user';
}

var_dump( $db );
```

The script will output this:

```
Unknown user

object(Mysql)#1 (3) { 
["conn":"Mysql":private]=> object(PDO)#2 (0) { } 
["error"]=> array(3) 
   { [0]=> string(5) "42S02" 
     [1]=> int(1146) 
     [2]=> string(39) "Table   'xxxx.Conference' doesn't exist" } 
["username"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Seeing as you are calling a variable you never set `$db->firstName` is this really working??

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: thanks for pointing that out. I did not test with a existing user. Corrected and updated the code.

Comment: no worries, wrote my own list of fixes based on his code. Hopefully there's enough to go on :-)

Comment: @JvdBerg fistname is not the same as username, if it was i wouldn't have posted a question considering i already have their username (it's what they typed in)

Comment: @CharlieYabben: but even in that case you would have got error(except the case if you have disabled error reporting)